# Jquery loop opacity fadein of images

Tags: jquery, loops, opacity

I have three images on my page:

```
    <div class="imagesmall fader1 opacity1"><img src="/images/mercedes.png" /></div>
<div class="imagesmall2 fader2 opacity1" style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="/images/house.png" /></div>
<div class="imagesmall2 fader3 opacity1" style="margin-left:5px;"><img src="/images/polo.png" /></div>
```

The class of opacity1 gives them all an opacity of 0.6 using css.

How can i, using Jquery, create a script that will set each of them individually to opacity 1.0 then back to opacity 0.6 and do this clockwise with a delay between each of them?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` and `animate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fadeTo()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) and [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    performEffect($("div.opacity1:first"), 1000);

    function performEffect($div, delay)
    {
        $div.fadeTo("slow", 1).fadeTo("slow", 0.6, function() {
            var $next = $div.nextAll("div.opacity1");
            if (!$next.length) {
                $next = $("div.opacity1");
            }
            performEffect($next.first().delay(delay), delay);
        });
    }
});
```

You can test that implementation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/U8spY/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var TimeOut = 4;
$('.opacity1').each(function() {
    setTimeout(function(ele) {
        ele.animate({opacity: 1}, 5000, function() { ele.animate({opacity: 0.6}); }
    }, 1000 * timeOut++, $(this));
};
```

I use this such of code to FadeOut some Message boxes, one by one.